# If filename has more than n characters, delete the last ones

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, find, replace

I'm kinda new with the unix shell, and I don't seem to find the answer of my problem :

I have a folder containing multiple files : a correct filename contains exactly 13 characters (numbers + letters + underscore). For example :

```
1305359000_PS.JPG
```

Some files are named incorrectly, the error always being in the last characters, such as :

```
9009015000_PS_1.jpg
```

I need to run a find / replace command that would work this way for all the files in my folder :

*IF filename > 13 characters (without the extension), then delete every character after the 13th.*

I tried some commands with *mmv* and *awk*, but i'm stuck so far.

**Edit : forgot to precise, the command should consider space(s) in the filename and delete them if present.**

Comment: What happens if you have `9009015000_PS_1.jpg` and `9009015000_PS_2.jpg`? If you simply delete after 13 then you'll end up with the same filename.

Comment: If duplicates are created, one can overwrite the other without causing any other problems. As long as the 10 first numbers are the same, the .jpg files are identical.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a bash shell

```
(shopt -s globstar; rename --no-act 's/^(.{13}).*/$1\.jpg/' **/*)
```

The `(....)` is so the `shopt -s globstar` option only applies to this one command - if for some reason you didnt have globbing already on.
If using zsh

```
rename --no-act 's/^(.{13}).*/$1\.jpg/' **/*
```

the `--no-act` switch will give a preview of what `rename` potentially will do.
If you are happy with the proposed changes, remove `-no-act` and your files will be bulk renamed.

Answer (score 0):

There may be another quickest solution available.
**This code is not considering the file name having space in it.**
 But you can give below code a try:

```
SHW@SHW:/tmp # for i in `find /home/user -type f`
do
      mv $i `echo $i | cut -c -13`.`$i | rev | cut -d'.' -f 1 | rev`
done
```

Comment: I forgot to precise that the script should consider space(s), sorry ! I edited the question accordingly.